# total of value in rows and cols in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, key, row

I made a table and I calculated the total of each row and each column. 
I would like to simplify my code below. 
Do you have any other ideas to reduce the code?
thanks you a lot

[image]

here is my code

```
$totalsanscontrat=0;
$totaldejacontrat=0;
$totalaveccontrat=0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
$total=0;

    print "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        print "<td align='center' bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><strong>$val</strong></td>";
        if($key!="codeDisc" ){
        $total+= $val;
        }
        if($key=="Candidat favorable sans contrat"){
            $totalsanscontrat+=$val;
        }
        if($key=="Candidat déjà eu un contrat"){
            $totaldejacontrat+=$val;
        }
        if($key=="Candidat avec contrat"){
            $totalaveccontrat+=$val;
        }
    }
    print "<td align='center' bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><strong>$total</strong></td>";
    print "</tr>";
}

<td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><strong><?php echo $totalsanscontrat;?></strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><strong><?php echo $totaldejacontrat;?></strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#F4F4F4"><strong><?php echo $totalaveccontrat;?></strong></td>
```

Comment: This question should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JayBlanchard questions involving existing code are off topic on P.SE just as they are on SO.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that @MichaelT. I have seen numerous posters sent there for code refactoring questions.

Comment: Have you considered doing a crosstab query instead of doing the calculations in the PHP @cyphos?

Comment: For do this crosstab query, you want say in SQL?

Comment: hello some ideas? thanks